# I cannot connect to MySQL from my android phone while I can from android studio emulator

Tags: android, mysql, emulation

I am running my android studio using emulator from my laptop and it works fine, but when I use my phone it give me error connection. I am using Wifi on my laptop, how I can solve this problem ?

Comment: Can you show table mysql.user content ?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it by connecting my laptop with cable instead of Wifi